# How to add top level KDoc for a file?

Tags: kotlin, kdoc

Is there a way to add a piece of top level KDoc for a Kotlin file?

Since Kotlin supports multiple variables, functions, classes, etc. in a single file, it makes sense to document the file as a whole. However, [Documenting Kotlin Code - Kotlin Programming Language](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kotlin-doc.html) seems not to have any instructions on this.

Comment: I haven't seen anything regarding documenting a singular file, as files are more related to grouping together related functionality when the actual unit is the package/module. From the same documentation page: _"Documentation for a module as a whole, as well as packages in that module, is provided as a separate Markdown file, and the paths to that file is passed to Dokka using the `-include` command line parameter or the corresponding parameters in Ant, Maven and Gradle plugins."_

Answer (score 1):

There's no such feature; however, packages and modules [can be documented](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/kotlin-doc.html#module-and-package-documentation) like in Java

In Dokka, additional documentation files are added with `include` property (e.g. [Gradle configuration](https://kotlin.github.io/dokka/1.5.30/user_guide/gradle/usage/#configuration-options)).